# Game of life in Go

Tags: go, game-of-life

I wrote the Game Of Life algorithm with Go. There are a million ways that we can implement the algorithm, but I want to know is it implemented in good-way or not?

I wonder how can I improve the performance and the code quality?

```
package main

import (
    "math"
    "math/rand"
    "strconv"
    "time"

    "github.com/nsf/termbox-go"
)

type Cell struct {
    X    int
    Y    int
    Dead bool
}

type GameOfLife struct {
    cells      [][]Cell
    Generation int
    Alives     int
}

var (
    maxRow, maxCol int
    pause          bool
    speed          time.Duration
    random         bool
)

func randInt(min int, max int) int {
    return min + rand.Intn(max-min)
}

func main() {
    pause = true
    err := termbox.Init()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    speed = 100
    random = false
    defer termbox.Close()
    termbox.SetInputMode(termbox.InputMouse)
    maxRow, maxCol = termbox.Size()
    maxCol -= 3
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UTC().UnixNano())
    b := initiate(false)
    eventQueue := make(chan termbox.Event)
    go func() {
        for {
            eventQueue <- termbox.PollEvent()
        }
    }()
loop:
    for {
        select {
        case ev := <-eventQueue:
            if ev.Type == termbox.EventKey {
                if ev.Key == termbox.KeyCtrlC {
                    break loop
                }

                if ev.Key == termbox.KeyCtrlS {
                    pause = !pause
                }

                if ev.Key == termbox.KeyCtrlN {
                    b = initiate(false)
                    pause = true
                }

                if ev.Key == termbox.KeyCtrlI {
                    speed++
                }

                if ev.Key == termbox.KeyCtrlD {
                    speed--
                }

                if ev.Key == termbox.KeyCtrlR {
                    b = initiate(true)
                }
            }
            if ev.Type == termbox.EventMouse {
                if ev.MouseX <= maxRow && ev.MouseY <= maxCol {
                    b.cells[ev.MouseY][ev.MouseX].Dead = false
                }
            }
            b.Print()
            termbox.Flush()

        default:
            if !pause {
                b.NextGen()
                time.Sleep(speed * time.Millisecond)
            }
            b.Print()
            termbox.Flush()
        }
    }
}

func initiate(random bool) *GameOfLife {
    b := &GameOfLife{
        cells: make([][]Cell, int(math.Max(float64(maxCol), float64(maxRow)))),
    }
    for i := 0; i <= maxCol; i++ {
        for j := 0; j <= maxRow; j++ {
            dead := true
            if random {
                if randInt(0, 100) < 50 {
                    dead = false
                }
            }
            c := Cell{
                X:    i,
                Y:    j,
                Dead: dead,
            }
            b.cells[i] = append(b.cells[i], c)
        }
    }

    return b
}

func (b *GameOfLife) NextGen() {
    duplicate := make([][]Cell, len(b.cells))
    for i := range b.cells {
        duplicate[i] = make([]Cell, len(b.cells[i]))
        copy(duplicate[i], b.cells[i])
    }
    b.Alives = 0
    for i := 0; i <= maxCol; i++ {
        for j := 0; j <= maxRow; j++ {
            ncnt := b.Nighbors(b.cells[i][j])
            if ncnt < 2 || ncnt > 3 {
                duplicate[i][j].Dead = true
            }
            if b.cells[i][j].Dead && ncnt == 3 {
                duplicate[i][j].Dead = false
            }
            if ncnt == 2 {
                duplicate[i][j] = b.cells[i][j]
            }

            if !duplicate[i][j].Dead {
                b.Alives++
            }
        }
    }
    b.Generation++
    b.cells = duplicate
}

func (b *GameOfLife) Nighbors(cell Cell) int {
    cnt := 0
    for x1 := cell.X - 1; x1 <= cell.X+1; x1++ {
        for y1 := cell.Y - 1; y1 <= cell.Y+1; y1++ {
            if x1 == cell.X && y1 == cell.Y {
                continue
            }
            if x1 < 0 || x1 >= maxCol {
                continue
            }
            if y1 < 0 || y1 >= maxRow {
                continue
            }
            if !b.cells[x1][y1].Dead {
                cnt++
            }
        }
    }
    return cnt
}

func (b *GameOfLife) Print() {
    termbox.Clear(termbox.ColorDefault, termbox.ColorDefault)

    for i := 0; i <= maxCol; i++ {
        for j := 0; j <= maxRow; j++ {
            ch := '█'
            if b.cells[i][j].Dead {
                ch = '░'
            }
            termbox.SetCell(j, i, ch, termbox.ColorDefault, termbox.ColorDefault)
        }
    }
    b.PrintStatus()
}

func (b *GameOfLife) PrintStatus() {
    statuses := []string{
        "Generation: " + strconv.Itoa(b.Generation) + " | Alives: " + strconv.Itoa(b.Alives) + " | Speed: " + (speed * time.Microsecond).String(),
        "Shortcuts: New (Ctrl+N) | Start/Pause(Ctrl+S) | Random (Ctrl+R) | Set Cell Alive (Mouse Click) | Speed Up (Ctrl+D) | Speed Down (Ctrl+I)",
    }
    for c, status := range statuses {
        for x, ch := range status {
            termbox.SetCell(x+1, maxCol+c+1, ch, termbox.ColorCyan, termbox.ColorDefault)
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: source code updated

[github repository](https://github.com/smoqadam/go-game-of-life)

Comment: Cross posteed on reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/a6278n/code_review_needed_for_conways_game_of_life/

Comment: great to see you used termbox. have had a look at `tcell` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I really liked the way you used `Termbox`; you should try `Tcell` as well for fun.

## Review

The function `initiate` is doing 2 jobs: generate the world and randomize.

They could be 2 functions as below:

```
func initiate(maxCol, maxRow) *GameOfLife {

    b := &GameOfLife{
        cells: make([][]Cell, int(math.Max(float64(maxCol), float64(maxRow)))),
    }
}
```

and Randomization could be a separate function.

Also, `randInt` could be better achieved with a seed:

```
seed := rand.New(rand.NewSource(time.Now().Unix()))
```

and then you may call `seed.Intn(30)` 30 here being the upper limit

Neighbors function `Nighbors` is bit messy; you could add more readability here. Which will just return Count of Neighbors and pass it to `Cell.NextState`

The `Cell` could be a struct and have the method `NextState`
e.g.

```
func (c *Cell) NextState(neighbours int) {
    if c.Alive && (neighbours < 2 || neighbours > 3) {
      c.Alive = false
  }

  if c.Alive && (neighbours == 2 || neighbours == 3) {
     c.Alive = true
  }

  if !c.Alive && neighbours == 3 {
     c.Alive = true
  }
}
```

---

You could have a separate directions struct and loop through each `Direction`,
and have another method to get the Direction Cell e.g.

```
func (b GameOfLife) getCell(x, y int) Cell {
    return b.cells[x+(y*wl.width)]
}
 
func(b GameOfLife) Plus(x, y int, direction Vector) Cell {
    return b.getCell(x+direction.x, y+direction.y)
}

var DirectionNames = strings.Split("n ne e se s sw w nw", " ")
var Directions = map[string]Vector{
    "n":  {0, -1},
    "ne": {1, -1},
    "e":  {1, 0},
    "se": {1, 1},
    "s":  {0, 1},
    "sw": {-1, 1},
    "w":  {-1, 0},
    "nw": {-1, -1},
}
```

In the same way, I see `NextGen` could be refactored into more functions to have better readability here.